# How can I set a default application prefix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I don't know the actual name for this, but instead of all my urls are working out to

```
mypoc.com/todo_list
mypoc.com/items
```

etc

I want

```
mypoc.com/wonderlist/todo_list
mypoc.com/wonderlist/items
```

How do I make this work out? The routes generated by Rails are fine for us but the urls for the javascript are not working out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding Custom Route to Rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19394192/adding-custom-route-to-rails-app)

Comment: is there a way to change this in the config.ru or somewhere similar. Our app has tons of absolute paths. If we change the application root that solves our problem.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking--you want the first URL segment to be a parameter you can use throughout the rest of the app?

Comment: I want every url to begin mypoc.com/wonderlist/ for my app. Even more specifically I want that to be the root, so all the places in my app where people made absolute paths everything still works without search and replace.

Comment: I don't know how familiar you are with rails, but have a look at the rails guides for routing: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Starting to find solutions. Setting RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT fixes most of the problems.